# How can we confirm that object is created in java

Tags: java

We all know that we can't instantiate an abstract class.
Some say when ever object is created, the constructor is called.
But when we instantiate a subclass of an abstract class, the abstract class-constructor is called. I believe if a constructor is called, it doesn't mean that the Object is created.
My question is: How can we confirm that the object is created:

```
public abstract class One
{
    public One()
    {
        System.out.println("One Object Constructor ");
    }

    public void test()
    {
    }

    public void testTwo()
    {
        System.out.println("Test Two");
    }
}

public class Two extends One
{
    public Two()
    {
        System.out.println("This is Two");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Two t = new Two();
    }
}
```

Output:

> One Object Constructor
>   This is Two

Comment: The constructor of the base is only called if you call it in your sub class

Comment: *"I believe if a constructor is called doesn't mean that Object is created."* And why do you believe that?

Comment: chokdee: the first thing a constructor does, whether you explicitly write the code or not, is call the constructor of the parent class.

Comment: The object is created when the constructor finishes and no exceptions are thrown (not by the constructor and not by initializers). That means if `Two t = new Two();` completes without a exception, you can be sure a `Two` object was created.

Comment: @Tom I believe  if a constructor is called  it just instantiate varibles

Comment: @LMK You believe wrong.

Comment: @LMK that's nonsense. unless the instance exists (what it doesn't before the constructor is called), there are no instance variables. if there are no instance variables, they can't be instantiated.

Comment: I think what @LMK might by trying to ask is: "is there a way to tell from an abstract superclass that the subclasses constructor completed successfully?". If that's the case, perhaps the question might need to be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is always called when an object/instance is created. If you have a class without a constructor it will in fact have a constructor that takes no arguments and calls a similar no-argument constructor in the superclass.

In addition all classes must call their superclass constructors, explicitly or implicitly (an implicit call only works if the superclass has a no-arguments constructor), so you can be sure that a constructor for each class in the chain has been called.

Perhaps you meant that in the constructor for One you cannot be sure that the actual instance has class One, it might also be a subclass? If so you can verify with getClass(), which returns the actual class.